# ctags not generating tags for custom language

Tags: exuberant-ctags

I am trying to extend ctags ( Exuberant Ctags 5.8 MacOSX ) with a custom language, however the tags file is always empty for the custom language.
In order to track down the issue. I used the example from the documentation.

I have the following .ctags in ~:

```
--langdef=swine
--langmap=swine:.swn
--regex-swine=/^def[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/d,definition/
```

When I run *ctags --list-kinds* I see:

```
...
swine
d  definition
```

I have a file *test.swn*:

```
def hehll
```

When I run *ctags -L test.swn* I see:

```
ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "def hehll" : No such file or directory
```

and the *tags* file generated looks like this:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
```

With other languages the tags file is filled as expected. Only with this custom extension it is empty.

I am not sure what I else I need to do to make ctags produce tags for the custom language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! Have to run:

```
 ctags test.swn
```

instead of

```
 ctags -L test.swn
```